# What is the usual term for the "data vs presentation" issue?

Tags: terminology, separation-of-concerns, presentation

I believe there is a common problem when programmers or software designers encode things which properly belong to the presentation as in the user interface into the data.

I'm sure it has a name everybody uses but just now when I wanted to suggest it as a topic for some people involved in data programming I couldn't think up any term that got useful Google hits.

One example of a problem of this sort would be including all your style information directly in your HTML.

One example of avoiding this problem would be keeping all your strings outside the code to allow localization and internationalization.

**What do programmers usually call this fault?**

(If this really belongs on programmers.SE feel free to migrate it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a concise name for this smell but it obviously violates the principle of "**separation of presentation and content**" and it's a violation of "**separation of concerns**". Wikipedia mentions the HTML example in the article on [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: Thanks, and it turns out that Wikipedia also has a separate article on ***[Separation of presentation and content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content)***.